# Ajax Search box shows Results from last Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So, I have this Request:

```
var searchResults = new Array();

var ajaxRequest = function (value, type) {
    if (typeof(type) === "undefined")
        type = "default";
    var ajaxData = {
        "title" : value,
        "limit" : getLimit(),
        "offset" : getOffset()
    }
    recentRequest = $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : getAjaxUrl(),
        dataType : "json",
        contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data : ajaxData,
        beforeSend : function (data)
        {
            if (searchResults[value] != undefined)
            {
                (type === "pagination") ? ajaxSuccessPagination(searchResults[value], ajaxData) : ajaxSuccess(searchResults[value], ajaxData);
                return false;
            }
        },
        success : function (data) {
            searchResults[value] = (data);
            (type === "pagination") ? ajaxSuccessPagination(data, ajaxData) : ajaxSuccess(data, ajaxData);
        },
        error : function (data) {
            ajaxError(data);
        }
    });
}
```

which if you type 'usb' and remove it, following with typing 'pencil' it will show the usb results first while you're having pencil filled in, now I want to make it so it will check if the results are the same as the currently typed in value. can Anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: you can bind the ajax call with on keyup event of your input field

Comment: @JPKim I had this before so that it would abort the first request if you pressed backspace, but of course this isnt the way to go. I want it to check if the results are relevant to the user input

Comment: @Niickies , I'm not sure if I understood right what you want.  you don't want to show results dynamically while typing, instead you want it when you're done with typing, right? You can do that with a "search" button or jquery's blur event or press enter key.

Comment: The site Im asking for is www.deschenker.nl and I dont really like some parts of The searching bar

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure if these are what you really want but anyway,

1) if you have a keywords dictionary (which you want to show search results only for valid keywords):

- modify the server page(getAjaxUrl()) to validate if the input string is valid keyword and return other value (like "FALSE" or "NOT VALID", anything that can distinguished to normal search results) if the input string is not in the dictionary.
- on "keyup" event, check if result is "FALSE(or anything you want)", and keep the previous result if so, or replace the search results with new one if result is not "FALSE".

---

2) if you don't have keywords dictionary and you just want to avoid blank search results :

- check if ajax search result contains more than one row (or other thing you can check the data) and keep the previous result if there's no results, or replace the search results if the result contains more than n row.

Comment: So, I want to have it check if the user input is the same as shown product list... if it isnt I want to hide the results

Comment: @Niickles , I think it's very difficult to achieve what you want unless you have a pre-defined keywords dictionary (or extract them from item names).

i.e., you don't know keyword "pen" is invalid while "pencil" is valid, if you don't have dictionary which contains only "usb", "pencil" and other keywords you think it's valid.

So build your own dictionary (in table, text file or any format you prefer) first and implement 1) method, if its what you want.
- you'll have to keep up to date the dictionary matched to your item data.

Answer (score 0):

managed to get it working, thanks anyway

```
var ajaxRequest = function (value, type) {
        if (typeof(type) === "undefined")
            type = "default";
        var ajaxData = {
            "title" : value,
            "limit" : getLimit(),
            "offset" : getOffset()
        }

        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url : getAjaxUrl(),
            dataType : "json",
            contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data : ajaxData,
            beforeSend : function (data)
            {
                if (searchResults[value] != undefined)
                {
                    (type === "pagination") ? ajaxSuccessPagination(searchResults[value], ajaxData) : ajaxSuccess(searchResults[value], ajaxData);
                    return false;
                }
            },
            success : function (data) {

                searchResults[value] = (data);
                if (document.getElementById('search').value == data.searched)
                {
                    (type === "pagination") ? ajaxSuccessPagination(data, ajaxData) : ajaxSuccess(data, ajaxData);
                }

            },
            error : function (data) {
                ajaxError(data);
            }
        });
    }
```